# Almost Sure convergence.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Given $(X_n, n\in\Bbb N)$ and $(Y_n, n\in\Bbb N)$ sequences of random Variables.

For all $n\in\Bbb N$ it is : $X_n=Y_n$ almost sure.

Now the question: Is then $P(X_n=Y_n \forall n\in\Bbb N)=1$?

---

Almost sure convergence means: $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X)=1$ iff $X_n=X$ almost sure.

Since I have for all $n\in\Bbb N$ $X_n=Y_n$ almost sure then I get: $X_n=Y_n$ almost sure iff $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=Y_n)=1$

How do I continue from here. Do I even have the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
P(\exists\, n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n\neq Y_n)=P\Big(\bigcup_n \,[X_n\neq Y_n]\Big)\leq \sum_nP(X_n\neq Y_n)=0
$$
and hence
$$
P(X_n=Y_n,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N})=1-P(\exists\, n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n\neq Y_n)=1.
$$

Comment: Thanks much :D. But do you think the "almost sure" part isn't a problem? I mean there could be one $n$ for which $X_n=Y_n$ isn't true hence why for this $n$ $P(X_n\neq Y_n)>0$. It's not sure convergence.

Comment: Don't you assume that $X_n=Y_n$ almost surely for all $n$?

Comment: Yes. I thought almost sure convergence should be used somehow to solve the problem.

Comment: If $X_n=Y_n$ almost surely for all $n$, then $P(X_n\neq Y_n)$ can't really be greater than 0, can it? This exercise has nothing to do with convergence.

Comment: @StefanHansen what does 'almost sure convergence' $\forall \ n$ mean? It is usually $\forall n>N, N=N(\omega)$?

Comment: @Alex: No idea.